# Enable submit button if one of textbox is filled

Tags: jquery

This is not working properly..
Because when we input in one of textfield and make it empty again then submit button gets disabled..

I need submit button to be worked only when one of my textfield is having value.

### test.html

```
        <form action=''>
            Location :<input name="location" id="keyword" type='text' /><br>
            Category :<input name="category" id="cat_keyword" type='text'><br>
            <input type="submit" id="loccat" class="send" value="Search">
        </form>
```

### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#keyword').val() == '' && $('#cat_keyword').val() == '') {
        $('#loccat').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else{
        $('#loccat').removeAttr('disabled');
    }

    //For location textfield
    $("#keyword").keyup(function(){
         if ($('#keyword').val() != '') {
            $('#loccat').removeAttr('disabled');
         }
         else{
                 $('#loccat').attr('disabled','disabled');
         }
     });                               

     //For category textfield
     $("#cat_keyword").keyup(function(){
         if ($('#cat_keyword').val() != '') {
             $('#loccat').removeAttr('disabled');
         }
         else{
             $('#loccat').attr('disabled','disabled');
         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to assign a class to the textboxes and then use the following procedure:

- Determine the number of textboxes filled
- Disable the `submit` button if that number is zero
- Otherwise enable the `submit` button
- Attach this code to the `input` event
- Trigger the `input` event when the page loads
- *You can increase the number of textboxes to whatever number you want and the same code would still work.*

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.formfield').on('input', function() {
        var nFilled = $('.formfield').filter(function() {
            return $.trim( this.value ) !== '';
        }).length;
        $('#loccat').prop('disabled', nFilled === 0);
    })
    .trigger('input');
});
```

**And now for the demo**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.formfield').on('input', function() {
        var nFilled = $('.formfield').filter(function() {
            return $.trim( this.value ) !== '';
        }).length;
        $('#loccat').prop('disabled', nFilled === 0);
    })
    .trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action=''>
  Location :
  <input name="location" id="keyword" type='text' class="formfield" />
  <br>Category :
  <input name="category" id="cat_keyword" type='text' class="formfield" >
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="loccat" class="send" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: This is much better than mine suggestion. thats some pretty code there Peter. Nicely done

Comment: Great! Glad you found this helpful @DanielWard.

Answer (score 1):

On both keyup events check both text filelds values. Add bellow code in both events.

```
 If($("cat_keyword").Val() != "" || $("keysod").Val() != "") {
     // enable button
 } else {
      // disable button
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **else** give **else if** condition checking if other field is also **empty**

```
 $("#keyword").keyup(function(){
                                if ($('#keyword').val() != '') {
                                $('#loccat').removeAttr('disabled');
                                }
                                else  if ($('#cat_keyword').val() == ''){
                                $('#loccat').attr('disabled','disabled');
                                }
                            });


                    //For category textfield
                    $("#cat_keyword").keyup(function(){
                                if ($('#cat_keyword').val() != '') {
                                $('#loccat').removeAttr('disabled');
                                }
                                else  if ($('#keyword').val() == ''){
                                $('#loccat').attr('disabled','disabled');
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using keypress() event, it starts every time you change the value of the textbox

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

in HTML

```
    <form action=''>
    Location :<input name="location" id="keyword" type='text' onchange="watchInput()" /><br>
    Category :<input name="category" id="cat_keyword" type='text' onchange="watchInput()"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="loccat" class="send" value="Search">
    </form>
```

and in JS

```
var watchInput = function() {
   if ($('#cat_keyword').val() || $('#keyword').val()) {
      $('#loccat').removeAttr('disabled');
   } else {
      $('#loccat').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

set submit button to disabled by default in the html, no need to do tat in JS.

```
<form id="myform" action=''>
Location :<input name="location" id="keyword" type='text' /><br>
Category :<input name="category" id="cat_keyword" type='text'><br>
<input type="submit" id="loccat" class="send" value="Search" disabled>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myform input").keyup(function(){
$("#myform input").each(function(){
if ($(this).val() != '') {
$('#loccat').removeAttr('disabled');
}
else{
 $('#loccat').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
});
});                               
});
```

Comment: monojit's suggestions is great. mine is more directed towards having more than 2 input elements in the form.

Answer (score 0):

**test.html**

```
<form action=''>
        Location :<input name="location" id="keyword" type='text' /><br>
        Category :<input name="category" id="cat_keyword" type='text'><br>
        <input type="submit" id="loccat" class="send" value="Search" disabled>
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

            var text1 =  $("#keyword").val();
            var text2 =  $("#cat_keyword").val();

            if(text1.length == 0 && text2.length == 0  ){
            $("#loccat").attr("disabled","disabled");
            }

            $("#keyword").keyup(function(){
                   var text1 =  $("#keyword").val();
                   var text2 =  $("#cat_keyword").val();
              if(text1.length == 0 && text2.length == 0  ){
                           $("#loccat").attr("disabled","disabled");
                   }else{
                           $("#loccat").removeAttr("disabled");
                   }
            });

            $("#cat_keyword").keyup(function(){
                   var text1 =  $("#keyword").val();
                   var text2 =  $("#cat_keyword").val();
              if(text1.length == 0 && text2.length == 0  ){
                           $("#loccat").attr("disabled","disabled");
                   }else{
                           $("#loccat").removeAttr("disabled");
                   }
            });

  });
```

A simple solution...working for me..

Comment: Good one @pathe.kiran. You know you can combine the two event listeners just by combining the selectors `$('#keyword,#cat_keyword').keyup(...` since the handlers are exactly the same. And if you'd like your code to catch *pasted* input then using `$('#keyword,#cat_keyword').on('input',...` should do it. ... Way to go!!